# Malloc isn't working in a function

Tags: c, function, malloc

malloc isn't allocating the memory requested in the function. I've tried searching on another malloc related questions/google, and I think what I wrote is supposed to function.
edit:~~~~ is filler code which really isn't supposed to be relevant to the problem =d

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <windows.h>

    typedef struct {

            int x;
            int y;        

    } Coordenada;

    int calculaCaminho(~~~~~Coordenada **posicoes) {
            int tam = 5;
    ~~~~

            *posicoes = (Coordenada*)malloc(tam*sizeof(Coordenada));

            //I can't access posicoes[k]->y or posicoes[k]->x for whatever value of k that was in the  
            //range of tam
    ~~~~


    return(~~~~);

    }
    main() {
    ~~~~      
            Coordenada *posicoes;
            npassos = calculaCaminho(~~~~, &posicoes);
    ~~~~
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What are these `~~~~`?

Comment: please provide reasonable contents, so that engineers can help you.

Comment: the "~~~~~~~" make me cannot reproduce the problem. Therefore no answer

Comment: how can i post the whole code then? its kinda long

Comment: Since you claim that the `~~~~` code is "filler code which ... isn't relevant", it should be easy for you to provide one of these: http://www.sscce.org/ .  And also see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please do not replace parts of code with garbage. If you think some parts are irrelevant, replace them with simpler code.

Comment: Is the return value of `main` irrelevant to you as well? Shouldn't there at least be some squiggles there? It's very confusing not knowing which things have been removed.

Comment: I'll let you in on a helpful practice: When something isn't working, save a copy of your code and then start tearing things out. When it starts working again, you'll know what the problem was because it was the last thing your tore out. You can also do this backwards, by building up from a blank project. The latter approach is my favorite, because it gives me a simple codebase that I can post to StackOverflow once I've identified the problem and don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
*posicoes = (Coordenada*)malloc(tam*sizeof(Coordenada));
```

After that, you could access `(*posicoes)[k].x`, but not `posicoes[k]->x`. If you use a temporary pointer for a moment, you'll notice it immediately:

```
Coordenada * ptr = (Coordenada*) malloc(tam*sizeof(Coordenada));

*posicoes        = ptr;
ptr[k].x         = 1; // ok
(*posicoes)[k].y = 2; // ok, same as ptr[k].y = 2;

// posicoes[k]->x = 0; // NOT ok
```

Answer (score 0):

> //i cant access posicoes[k]->y or posicoes[k]->x for whatever value of
>   k that was in the
>               //range of tam

You should access them as follows :

```
  posicoes[0][k].y ....
```

or

```
  (*posicoes)[k].y ....
```

`(*posicoes)` and `posicoes[0]` will give you access to the first element of allocated memory. After that you can access elements by their index relatively to first element..

Answer (score 0):

You can access  `x` and `y` like mentioned here..

```
*posicoes = (Coordenada*)malloc(tam*sizeof(Coordenada));
for(int k = 0 ; k < tam ; k++)
{
    (*posicoes)[k].x = k;
    (*posicoes)[k].y = 10*k;
}
```

and the same can be access in `main` like:

```
for(int k = 0 ; k < 5 ; k++)
{               
    //print ..  posicoes[k].x 
    //print ..  posicoes[k].y 
}
```